# ESLint React Parsing Error

Tags: meteor, reactjs, eslint

So I followed the instructions at guide.meteor.com to set up my package.json eslintConfig.

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "plugins": [
    "meteor"
  ],
  "extends": [
    "airbnb/base",
    "plugin:meteor/recommended"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "meteor/eventmap-params": [
      2,
      {
        "templateInstanceParamName": "instance"
      }
    ],
    "import/no-unresolved": [
      2,
      {
        "ignore": [
          "^meteor/"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "never"
    ]
  }
}
```

It works fine until I try and use React.

main.js:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('render-target'))
})
```

That throws the error: `[eslint] Parsing error: Unexpected token <`

I have the react plugin:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^2.9.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^8.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^1.6.1",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^1.0.4",
  "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^3.5.2",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1"
}
```

I've tried following examples from Google but none of them helped. I've tried adding 'react' and 'eslint-plugin-react' to the plugins bit and nothing changed. I'm gobsmacked the solution wasn't provided in the ESLint section of the meteor guide. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Try installing `babel-eslint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `babel-eslint` and to your `.eslintrc` add `"parser": "babel-eslint"`. You're missing the ES6 transpiling so eslint just crashes.

Comment: I think Meteor comes pre-packaged with babel... Or do I need to add it as a dev dependency?

Comment: Ah yes, adding to to the dev dependencies did the trick. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install `babel-eslint`. Espree (native ESLint parser) fully supports ES6, ES7 and Object Rest/Spread.
The reason ESLint stopped parsing your file is because you haven't enabled `jsx`, so it will consider it as an incorrect syntax.

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "jsx": true
  }
}
```

Add the above snippet to your config file and it should start working. For more information, you can read [Specifying Parser Options](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-parser-options)